# Calculated column to find due date

Tags: javascript, custom-list, date-time, calculated-column-formula

I need to create a calculated column that will read in the date from one column and compare it to today's date. The problem is the the date column is a dropdownlist with dates entered in the format of (MM/YY).

So if today's date is 04/15 and the date the user selected is 03/15 then the calculation would subtract the days in between the dates and in my case I would like them to not be exact but 30 day increments since we don't have exact dates in my columns. So if the dates came out to be 30 then an extra column would have colors that would be Red in the case since the due date is within 30 days.

I was using this formula page to find something comparable to what would work for me in this case since the dates aren't in an actual date field.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Any ideas on how to get started with this?

Answer (score 1):

No matter what some blogs tell you can **not** use TODAY in a Calculated Column.

See the [Use javascript/jquery to see if items in list are due soon in Sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139261/use-javascript-jquery-to-see-if-items-in-list-are-due-soon-in-sharepoint-2013/139354#139354]) topic for some alternatives, like CSR/JSlink, XSLT or stuffing Javascript in a Calculated Column